# How to get the height of the Markdown Widget content using flutter_markdown?

Tags: flutter, markdown

I'm attempting to render multiple markdown widgets using [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) in a `Column` widget. If I place `Markdown` Widget straight away in the `children: []` array I get an error: "Cannot hit test a render box with no size". Wrapping the Markdown widget in a fixed height container solves the issue. However this is a big issue for me. I need to let the markdown content stretch to its max height and then render another such widget with different inner content. Any idea on how can I either get the content height or disable the scrolling behaviour?

````
Container(
  height: 300, // Without specifying the height
  child: Markdown(
    selectable: true,
    data: """
# Hello World!

_I'm a Markdown file._

This is some code:

```
class MyClass {
final String name = "Paul";
}
```

  """,
  ),
),
````

Answer (score 3):

By browsing the source code of the library I've learned that there is block that does not have built in scroll, `MarkdownBody`.

```
MarkdownBody(
  selectable: true,
  data: text,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set shrinkWrap equal to true.

```
Markdown(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   data: "__STRONG__",
)
```